git: Custom diff parsing for python file embedded in JSON format .v5python
The VEX Robotics competition (https://www.vexrobotics.com/) seems to use a very odd file format for python files.  The competition is an educational platform for children in school (elementary, middle, and high school).  The file extension is .v5python and it is a python file, but embedded as a single line JSON format file.  For reference, a shortened version of a file is below.
{"mode":"Text","textContent":"#region VEXcode Generated Robot Configuration\nfrom vex import *\nimport urandom\n\n# Brain should be defined by default\nbrain=Brain()\n\n# Robot configuration code\n\n\n# wait for rotation sensor to fully initialize\nwait(30, MSEC)\n#endregion VEXcode Generated Robot Configuration\n\n# ------------------------------------------\n# \n# \tProject:\n#\tAuthor:\n#\tCreated:\n#\tConfiguration:\n# \n# ------------------------------------------\n\n# Library imports\nfrom vex import *\n\n# Begin project code\n\ndef pre_autonomous():\n    # actions to do when the program starts\n    brain.screen.clear_screen()\n    brain.screen.print(\"pre auton code\")\n    wait(1, SECONDS)\n\ndef autonomous():\n    brain.screen.clear_screen()\n    brain.screen.print(\"autonomous code\")\n    # place automonous code here\n\ndef user_control():\n    brain.screen.clear_screen()\n    # place driver control in this while loop\n    while True:\n        wait(20, MSEC)\n\n# create competition instance\ncomp = Competition(user_control, autonomous)\npre_autonomous()\n","textLanguage":"python","rconfig":[],"slot":1,"platform":"V5","sdkVersion":"20220726.10.00.00","appVersion":"2.4.0","minVersion":"2.4.0","fileFormat":"1.2.0","icon":"","targetBrainGen":"First","target":"Physical"}

You can see that it is JSON formatted, and the field textContent seems to have a python 'file' in it.  However, you can likely see the issue with git: it sees the file as a single line.  Getting blame support or even get diff to give functional output is difficult.  I thought I could use .gitattributes for *.v5python and perhaps override the format for python (perhaps *.v5python    text diff=python), but that didn't work as obviously, it isn't parsing due to the embedded JSON.  I tried reading up on the .gitattributes file documentation (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), and I think that perhaps even modifying the hunk header or word diff regular expressions, I could somehow 'teach' the diff to understand how to treat the file.  However, I am not sure if I am barking up the right tree.
We are tying to introduce the idea of version control to the team and have taught them about git.
However, when loading .v5python files into github or any other git UI tool, like the Windows git-fork tool, the outputs are mangled.
The ideal is that the python portion of the 'file' is treated like a python file, where every line is treated as a new line in the diff, separated by the \n character.  I am trying to get that section of the code to play nicely so that standard git operations are meaningful with it; that branch comparisons, merges, blame, and change snippets displays are like that of .py files.  I also know that the sections before and after the textContent entry will likely cause issues for the python filter in git (and github) doing syntax highlighting and other nice to haves, so that would be great to come up with a way to get those parts to be largely ignored.  These sections are unlikely to change frequently, if at all.
Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can get git to create meaningful diffs from this file format?
Additional info: Unfortunately, we can't just use .py files as they (VEX) have a custom IDE which programs the actual controllers.  It won't open a .py file.  I thought about writing a custom tool to somehow synchronize a .v5python file into a sibling .py file, but the two way sync seems easy to screw up and unnecessarily complex of a solution.  I am hoping there is someway of teaching the diff tool to understand the format, even if the diffs have to be local machine generated by a tool like git-fork.

Whatever you would define in .gitattributes or .git/config it wouldn't be used at GitHub for security purposes — no Git hostings allow users to run user-defined commands. So forget about fixing GitHub interface. The only way to fix it to commit the file in the proper Python format.

Venues to try: 1. one way sync (you don't need two way sync if you only need diff and GitHub interface). 2. A smudge filter. 3. A custom diff driver. Only sync will work for GitHub.

This seems like a rotten way to introduce anyone to git: the file you're working with doesn't appear to be something that a person edits; it looks like something that is maintained by some sort of tooling. That creates all kinds of hassles. While the suggestions here (a custom diff driver, or smudge/clean filters) will get you something that works, you're forcing people to learn techniques that generally mean "something is wrong with this setup". If you want to teach version control, have folks edit regular python files with a simple text editor.

@larsks - I am not looking to teach version control as a lesson.  I am looking to figure out how to have multiple kids work on the same codebase without trampling each other.    Is that not what version control is for?

The problem is that the kids aren't editing the code. There is some sort of tool that sits between them and the code. If you can arrange things so that the kids are actually editing code files, things will be much easier. You can certainly use version control with those weird .v5python files, but it's going to be much more difficult and it won't be a very representative experience.

Sounds like you want to teach your kids about the real world and this "vex" cadre wants to wall them in and charge money for tidbits of the word as they want to present it. [digs around a bit:] Yup. Oh, look: endless separately-priced options! What a wonderful world! Throw away the debossed-logo rings you paid us money for, and use the new embossed-logo rings we're going to sell you again! Don't use any of the tools people use in the field we say we're teaching your kids about, only give us money! Use our tools! Then give us more!

I don't know how much this helps, but here is how you could create a custom diff driver:
Create in the repository filters/v5python-diff with the following content:
#!/bin/bash
#
# path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode

path=$1
old_file=$2
new_file=$5

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d diffXXXXXX)
trap 'rm -rf $tmpdir' EXIT

mkdir "$tmpdir/a" "$tmpdir/b"

jq -r .textContent "$old_file" >"$tmpdir/a/$path"
jq -r .textContent "$new_file" >"$tmpdir/b/$path"

(cd "$tmpdir" && git diff --no-ext-diff --no-index "a/$path" "b/$path")
exit 0

And make sure the file is executable:
chmod 755 filters/v5python-diff

Configure git to know about the custom diff script:
git config diff.v5python.command filters/v5python-diff

And configure .gitattributes so that git knows to use the v5python diff driver for *.v5python files:
cat >> .git/info/attributes <<EOF
*.v5python diff=v5python
EOF

(I'm using the repository-local .git/info/attributes file here; you could use .gitattributes if you want this config to be part of the repository.)
Git will use this script automatically when using git diff:
$ git diff HEAD^ example.v5python
diff --git a/a/example.v5python b/b/example.v5python
index e4ff94b..f7ef6b8 100644
--- a/a/example.v5python
+++ b/b/example.v5python
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@ brain=Brain()
 
 
 # wait for rotation sensor to fully initialize
-wait(30, MSEC)
+wait(60, MSEC)
 #endregion VEXcode Generated Robot Configuration
 
 # ------------------------------------------

And explicitly if you pass --ext-diff to git log or git show:
$ git log -p --ext-diff -1
commit 0e04895dac2ae8b0393ebeb370e69639bcad23c2
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@example.com>
Date:   Sun Jul 14 17:30:08 2024 -0400

    Increase wait time

diff --git a/a/example.v5python b/b/example.v5python
index e4ff94b..f7ef6b8 100644
--- a/a/example.v5python
+++ b/b/example.v5python
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@ brain=Brain()
 
 
 # wait for rotation sensor to fully initialize
-wait(30, MSEC)
+wait(60, MSEC)
 #endregion VEXcode Generated Robot Configuration
 
 # ------------------------------------------

This is only useful for displaying diffs between commits; it won't ever touch the content of the files and cannot be used to enable, say, merging of overlapping commits. For that you could try using a smudge/clean filter, but I have substantial concerns about the usability of that solution.
